# how can i make a loop of data having in listbox in vb?

Tags: vb.net, listbox

i have a listbox having value of integer  . i want to make 2 loop

```
 Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1
 TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()
 words = TextLine.Split(New Char() {","c})
 ListBox1.Items.Add(words(3) & "," & words(4))
    Loop
 For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
   Dim tempstr = ListBox1.Items.Item(i)
   tempstr = ListBox1.Items(i)
   Value = tempstr.Split(","c)
   Data= Value(0)
  Next
```

i want to make 2 datalist

1. Remove the first item of value1
2. Remove the last item of value1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can take the loop like this .
  In the first you got the value from first to last -1
  In the sec you got from second(with out first) to last one

```
 For j As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 2
  Dim first = ListBox1.Items(j).ToString
  Dim sec = ListBox1.Items(j+1).ToString
 Next
```

I think this sloves your problem